# Change resultant's key name in cube.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cube.js

Currently, I am using the react dashboard for frontend and cube.js for the backend.
Result which I get from the backend is in the form of json and each key represents the column of my database. 
Resultant example:

```
{
  user.email:"xxx",
  user.id:"xxx",
}
```

Where User is my table and email is the column name. This is causing me problem while rendering the data using react-table.
Is there any way I can give alias to columns and get data like this:

```
{
  email:"xxx",
  id:"xxx"
}
```

Comment: in javascript you can use `object["user.email"]` or you can get that value like that and transform it into your own object.

Comment: I can't. React-table's accessor doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define your accessor as a function as the sample in npm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#example

```
{
    id: 'email', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Email',
    accessor: d => d['user.email'] // Custom value accessors!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can access the value like this `object["user.email"]`

You said you can't use it like that in `react-tables`, so you're going to have to transform it into another object that the table can accept.

Something like this

```
var user = {
   email: object["user.email"]
}
```

Now you can access the newly transformed object like this.

```
user.email
```

Comment: This would work if I have less amount of data. But would be very inefficient for large data.